# Geb: List of Page contents

Tags: groovy, geb

I have a `Page` class as

```
class SignUpPage extends Page {
    static url = "signup"
    static at = { waitFor { title.startsWith("Join") } }
    static content = {
        firstNameField { $("input", name:"firstName") }
        lastNameField  { $("input", name:"lastName") }
        emailField     { $("input", name:"email") }
        passwordField  { $("input", name:"password") }
    }
}
```

I want to add a `populateFields` method to this class. This will allow me to call this method to populate the text fields from my test cases. This method has one argument passed in - a `Map` that allows me to override certain field values as necessary from my test cases.

**The problem** is that I don't know how I can iterate over the 'content' of the page. To make this clearer look at the code below:

```
class SignUpPage extends Page {
    static url = "signup"

    // .. as defined above ..

    def populateFields(customValues = [:]) {

        // I want to iterate of the textFields here
        // Something like...

        textFields = this.metaclass.methods.findAll {
            it.name.endsWith("Field")
        }

        textFields.each {
             // populate with data
        }
    } 
}
```

This **doesn't work**.

How do I get the content of the closure 'content'?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a much easier way of implementing it and you don't need to iterate over contents of your page object. Given the keys in your map are name attributes of the inputs you want to modify, you can do the following:

```
def populateFields(customValues = [:]) {
    def form = $('form') //can be any element that is enclosing all of your inputs

    customValues.each { key, value ->
        form[key] = value
    }
}
```

Have a look at the section on [form control shortcuts](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#form_control_shortcuts) in the manual to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If content becomes too complicated to use the available tools you could always create a list of the page contents in your content.

```
static content = {
    username { module $(... }
    contactTitle { $(... }
    contactGivenName { $(... }
    contactFamilyName { moduleList $(... }

    pageFields {
    [
    username,
    contactTitle,
    contactGivenName,
    contactFamilyName,
       ]
   }
}

def populateFields(valueList) {
    pageFields.each {
        it.value(somevaluefromList)
    }

}
```